# Get Regex Expression Before a Condition

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I wanted to output the following based on regex expressions. I wanted to have some kind of reusability based on filename formats

****Filename formats****

```
   export const datas = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "CODE_SLOT",
        codePosition: 0,
        codeType: "_",
        slotPosition: 1,
        slotType: "_",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "CODE-SLOT",
        codePosition: 0,
        codeType: "-",
        slotPosition: 1,
        slotType: "-",
      },
    ];
```

**Code for product code**

```
export const getProductCode = (code, codePosition, codeType) => {
  return (
    code.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").split(codeType)[codePosition] ||
    code.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").split(codeType)[0] ||
    ""
  );
};



const images = [{
    name: "toys-blue_wide.jpg"
}]

const selectedFileNameFormat = datas[0]

const output = images.map((image) => ({
  productCode: getProductCode(
    image?.name,
    selectedFileNameFormat?.codePosition,
    selectedFileNameFormat?.codeType
  ),
}));

console.log(output)
```

**Expected Output for Product Code**

```
productCode: toys-blue
```

**Code for slot**

```
export const getSlot = (slot, slotPosition, slotPosition) => {
  return (
    slot.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").split(slotPosition)[slotPosition] ||
    slot.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").split(slotPosition)[0] ||
    ""
  );
};
    const images = [{
    name: "toys-blue_wide.jpg"
}]
const selectedFileNameFormat = datas[0]

const output = images.map((image) => ({
  slotCode: getSlot(
    image?.name,
    selectedFileNameFormat?.codePosition,
    selectedFileNameFormat?.codeType
  ),
}));
```

**Expected Output for slot**

```
slotCode: wide
```

Comment: Dude, It is not so clear what exactly do you want?

Comment: @decpk. I have to sets of expected output. First expected output is the `productCode` and the second expected output `slotCode`. I wanted them to base on the file `Filename formats`.  The `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to parse/extract from a string, i.e. "toy-blue_wide.jpg", a `productCode` everything *before* the `"_"` character, i.e. `"toy-blue"`, and a `slotCode`, everything *after* the `"_"` excluding the file extension. You can use a single REGEX and capture these two parts into their respective groups.

```
/^(.*)_(.*)\./
```

The first parens captures the product code and the second captures the slot code. Using [RexExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) you can execute a search over each filename and extract an array of matches.

```
const [, productCode, slotCode] = /^(.*)_(.*)\./.exec(name);
```

Notice also that when using array destructuring assignment we're skipping the first element. This is because the first element returned from `.exec` is the full string of characters matched, whereas indices 1..n are the captured groups.

```js
const images = [{
  name: "toys-blue_wide.jpg"
}];

const codeAndSlotRegex = /^(.*)_(.*)\./;

images.forEach(({ name }) => {
  const [, productCode, slotCode] = /^(.*)_(.*)\./.exec(name);
  console.log({ productCode, slotCode });
});
```

### Update

To allow for dynamically selecting the filename parser I'd specify a specific REGEX matcher for each format you want to parse.

```
const fileNameFormats = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Code-Slot",
    matcher: /^(.*)-(.*)\./
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Code_Slot",
    matcher: /^(.*)_(.*)\./
  }
];
```

Iterate over the array of images and use the specifically selected matcher. Provide a fallback array value in the case that matching fails, and default code and slot values.

```
const output = images.map((image) => {
  const [, productCode = "", contentSlot = ""] = selectedFileNameFormat.matcher.exec(
    image?.name
  ) ?? [];
  return {
    productCode,
    contentSlot
  };
});
```

[image: Edit get-regex-expression-before-a-condition]

Comment: @Joseph I dunno, that other post doesn't really explain anything and all the codesandbox does is select from two options and log the local state. I'm not sure what you want us to understand from it.

Comment: @Joseph Ok, but I'm asking what the options mean. If user selects "Code-Slot", what is supposed to happen next, what does selecting that option mean? Same for if user selects "Code_Slot"? I thought you were wanting to pick a file name format to parse. Is it literally as simple as just splitting on the symbol between "code" and "slot"?

Comment: @Joseph I see now. Shall I update answer here then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239469/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-joseph).